# TFS2010 Branching into a subfolder of another branch

Tags: version-control

We have a folder structure in our source control where some things are branched, and some aren't.
The branched stuff follows a (standard?) pattern of `Production`, `Main`, `Development` branches plus the occasional branch for a large project.

Sometimes as part of those large projects web branch some of the stuff that is normally not branched. For instance we might branch `$/source/Libraries/LibraryA` into `$/source/branches/Project1/LibraryA` to make some major `Project1`-related changes to it.
Then when `Project1` is nearing release, we reverse integrate both from `Project1` into the `Main` branch, and from `Project1/LibraryA` into the `Libraries` folder.

Well, that's how we did it in TFS2008. Recently we moved to TFS2010 which seems to keep track of what things are branches and what aren't. So when we try to branch `LibraryA` as a subfolder of `Project1`, we get and error message that `Project1` is already a branch.

Is there a way around this? Are we using TFS2010 wrong, and if so, what would be the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I detailed in "[Team Foundation Server and branching characteristics, compared to others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979832/team-foundation-server-and-branching-characteristics-compared-to-others/1980560#1980560)", the branching model of TFS has evolved quite a bit between TFS2008 and TFS2010.
The [TFS Branching Guide](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/) and [Branching Guidance](http://branchingguidance.codeplex.com/) can help.

See [this thread](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=213780) for more details on branch management:

> In TFS 2010, a user must have Manage Branch permission set to Allow for a given path to do the following:

- Convert folders to branches (and branches back to folders)
- Update metadata for a branch (i.e. owner, description)
- Create additional child branches from the original branch
- Change the relationships between branches with merge relationships (i.e. reparenting branches)

W In TFS 2010, a user must have Merge permission set to Allow for a given path can do the following:

- Pend merge operations on branches, folders, and files under the specified path

> Manage Branch and Merge permissions are new for TFS 2010.
>
> Branching in TFS 2010 is a server-side operation.
>   Presumably, if you have a team of developers and you grant them check-in and check-out permissions without merge or manage branch permissions - these developers would be able to create workspaces that map whatever branches they need to work on to local folders on their hard drive.
>
> In VS 2010, Branches are now a first-class object and as such have a branch icon that easily distinguishes a branch from a folder (with a folder icon).

See also [this thread](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=81574) with a scenario closer to your situation.

> For shared libraries, I generally prefer using file references rather than project references.
>   I would have a separate TeamProject for developing the source code for these libraries.
>   You could deploy the assemblies to a shared folder and reference these assemblies from the various projects that use them.
>   This approach would permit you to have multiple versions of the assemblies. Each project would create file references to the particular version they require.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I was trying to create another branch in DEV (in separate folder) from MAIN and this error popped up.

What resolved this problem for me was to create a new branch in the root and later move it to Dev.